# Group consecutive similar array of elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

Here is my simple array of objects

```
const array = [
    { name: 'a', val: '1234' },
    { name: 'b', val: '5678' },
    { name: 'c', val: '91011' },
    { name: 'c', val: '123536' },
    { name: 'e', val: '5248478' },
    { name: 'c', val: '5455' },
    { name: 'a', val: '548566' },
    { name: 'a', val: '54555' }
]
```

I need to group consecutive name elements and push the corresponding `val`. So the expected output should be

```
const array = [
    { name: 'a', vals: '1234' },
    { name: 'b', vals: '5678' },
    { name: 'c', vals: ['91011', '123536'] },
    { name: 'e', vals: '5248478' },
    { name: 'c', vals: '5455' },
    { name: 'a', vals: ['548566', '54555'] }
]
```

I tried it But could not get over it. Please help

```
const output = []
const result = array.reduce((a, c) => {
    if (a.name === c.name) {
        output.push(a);
    }
}, []);
```

Comment: Please add the code you've tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array like this. Compare the current `name` with previous item's name. If they are not the same, add a new item to the accumulator. If they are the same, then use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) the merge `val` with the last item in accumulator. `concat` is used because `vals` could either be a string or an array.

```js
const array = [
    { name: 'a', val: '1234' },
    { name: 'b', val: '5678' },
    { name: 'c', val: '91011' },
    { name: 'c', val: '123536' },
    { name: 'e', val: '5248478' },
    { name: 'c', val: '5455' },
    { name: 'a', val: '548566' },
    { name: 'a', val: '54555' }
]

const merged = array.reduce((acc, { name, val }, i, arr) => {
  // check if name is same as the previous name
  if (arr[i - 1] && arr[i - 1].name === name) {
    const prev = acc[acc.length - 1]; // last item in the accumulator
    prev.vals = [].concat(prev.vals, val)
  } else
    acc.push({ name, vals: val })
    
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(merged)
```

Comment: Awesome. Could you please let me know what is `}, [])` at last of the reduce?

Comment: That's the [`initialValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Syntax) parameter of `reduce`. It is the accumulator object.

Answer (score 2):

You were actually quite close:

```
 const output = [];
 array.reduce((a, c) => {
    if (a.name === c.name) { // current element equals previous element, lets merge
       a.values.push(c.val);
    } else output.push(a = { name: c.name, values: [c.val] ); // otherwise add new entry
    return a; // the current element is the next previous
  }  , {}); // start with an empty a, so that c always gets pushed
```

Note that it makes little sense to store numbers as string  though.

Comment: Oh, cause its `val` not `value` ... and you wanted to build up arrays ov values, not sum them up (missunderstood your question) ... edited

Comment: Now `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
 `

Comment: Oh, and again: apologies, my mistake. Now that the accumulator is different from an element, we need to distinguish those (and pass on the right one)